# how enable google chrome browser to save passwords for couchdb futon

Tags: couchdb-futon

chrome Version 37.0.2062.103 
is unable to save passwords with futon on couchdb.
all other browsers like firefox and IE saving it fine. 
i checked the form html and the syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

chrome seems not to be able to saves futons users and password sby default,
you need to change couchdb config file and use basic auth

in the local.ini config file of couchdb enable the section below.

[httpd]
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"

after chrome will be able to save the password

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to:

- log in normally
- change the path of the address bar from `_utils/database.html` to `_logs`
- confirm the browser question